# insert text into the border in svg

Tags: html, svg

I have a svg that has a border painted on the perimeter. Can you please tell me how to set a text for this border?

I need to have text on each part of the border - on the `sides`, `top` and `bottom` of the border. And the text should be in the `center` of each part of the border.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 694 426">
    <g>
        <path d="M659.89 4.56006L34.89 4.66006V4.56006H5.48999V421.66H689.29V4.56006H659.89ZM34.89 399.56V26.7601H659.89V399.46L34.89 399.56Z" fill="#34428B"></path>
        <path d="M343.09 20.06L343.99 20.86L347.49 17.36L350.99 20.86L351.89 20.06L348.39 16.56L351.89 13.06L350.99 12.16L347.49 15.66L343.99 12.16L343.09 13.06L346.59 16.56L343.09 20.06Z" fill="#000010"></path>
        <path d="M34.79 4.56006V49.1601" stroke="#272425" stroke-width="1.24" stroke-miterlimit="9.62"></path>
        <path d="M242.69 4.56006V49.1601" stroke="#272425" stroke-width="1.24" stroke-miterlimit="9.62"></path>
        <path d="M451.89 4.56006V49.1601" stroke="#272425" stroke-width="1.24" stroke-miterlimit="9.62"></path>
        <path d="M659.79 4.56006V49.1601" stroke="#272425" stroke-width="1.24" stroke-miterlimit="9.62"></path>
        <path d="M659.79 26.86H34.79V399.36H659.79V26.86Z" stroke="#000008" stroke-width="1.24" stroke-miterlimit="9.62"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**SNIPPET TWO**

```css
#text-group > text {
    fill: white;
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 694 426">
    <g>
        <path d="M659.89 4.56006L34.89 4.66006V4.56006H5.48999V421.66H689.29V4.56006H659.89ZM34.89 399.56V26.7601H659.89V399.46L34.89 399.56Z" fill="#34428B"></path>
    </g>
    
    <g id='text-group'>
        <text x="50%" y="21" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">TOP</text>
        <text x="50%" y="98%" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">BOTTOM</text>

        <text x="22"  y="50%" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">LEFT</text>
        <text x="95%" y="50%" transform="rotate(90 667, 213)">RIGHT</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I just want to have `transform rotate` for TOP and BOTTOM as in the snippet above, but I don't know what values to specify

Comment: In order to center the text around the x and y values you can use `text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"` Also do not forget to add a fill attribute for the text.

Comment: @enxaneta, thanks for telling me how to center, but how do I add the text itself to each border of the side? - top, bottom and sides

Comment: You will need to use a text element, for example this: <text x="347.5" y="17" fill="black" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">some text</text>

Comment: @enxaneta, thanks, yes, it displays the text at the top. but i don't know svg well. please help to make it for all sides

Comment: You can use `textPath` if you want it to follow the border, otherwise 4x `text` element positioned on the borders. Could you show us your attempt? There are tons of questions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `<text>` nodes with some x/y to position them on the border.

To rotate the text on the left/right side, use a `rotate(90)` with the additional position of the text.

```css
#text-group > text {
    fill: white;
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 694 426">
    <g>
        <path d="M659.89 4.56006L34.89 4.66006V4.56006H5.48999V421.66H689.29V4.56006H659.89ZM34.89 399.56V26.7601H659.89V399.46L34.89 399.56Z" fill="#34428B"></path>
    </g>
    
    <g id='text-group'>
        <text x="50%" y="21">TOP</text>
        <text x="50%" y="98%">BOTTOM</text>

        <text x="22"  y="50%" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">LEFT</text>
        <text x="95%" y="50%" transform="rotate(90 667, 213)">RIGHT</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

Based on OP's comment, mirroring the TOP text can be done with the same transform.

The values needed are: `transform="rotate(180 347 10)"`, where

1. `180` degrees to flip the text
2. `347`, that's half the value you provided in the `viewBox`
3. `15`, spacing from top, half (rounded) `y`

```css
#text-group > text {
    fill: red;
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 694 426">
    <g>
        <path d="M659.89 4.56006L34.89 4.66006V4.56006H5.48999V421.66H689.29V4.56006H659.89ZM34.89 399.56V26.7601H659.89V399.46L34.89 399.56Z" fill="#34428B"></path>
    </g>
    
    <g id='text-group'>
        <text x="50%" y="21" transform="rotate(180 347 15)">TOP</text>
        <text x="50%" y="98%">BOTTOM</text>

        <text x="22"  y="50%" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">LEFT</text>
        <text x="95%" y="50%" transform="rotate(90 667, 213)">RIGHT</text>
        
        
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: can you help me please? can you add `transform rotate` for top and bottom text. i just want to change the orientation of this text. thanks!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean, you want the top.bottom to be upside-down? This should be included in your original question btw.

Comment: And un-accepting answers after changing the questions isn't really nice...

Comment: wow... i didnt refuse to answer! I dont know how it happened!

Comment: i checked the checkbox back, but honestly, I didnt turn it down. i want to have the same `transform rotate` rules for top and bottom text. because i will change the orientation of the text - `rotate`

Comment: my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121024/insert-text-into-the-border-in-svg) you replied to has been deleted and your reply has been moved to this question, which I had previously deleted.

Comment: Okea weird, but nice it's fixed :D. Could you please add a comment here what you want me to change in my answer? Top/Bottom text reversed? Then I'll update the snippet for you.\

Comment: I just want to do like this is just an example - `<text x="50%" y="21" transform="rotate(-90 26, 213)">TOP</text>` and there are values ``, and I don't know what values I should set for TOP and BOTTOM

Comment: I've added a second snippet with a description at the bottom of the question. please. check it out

Comment: Ah oke, but 90 degrees on top/bottom is kinda weird, you will get vertical text then that will probably overlap theborder, don't you want 180 degrees to 'flip' the text?

Comment: I've added another snippet that mirrors the top text. Hope that is what you'le looking for.

Comment: thank you. would that be `<text x="50%" y="98%" transform="rotate(any 347, 411)">BOTTOM</text>` for the BOTTOM?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to draw *guidelines* over your rectangle and align text on each line.

Or draw your rectangle with *individual* paths.

You do have to learn SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

You can do it with 1 path, set the `pathLength` attribute to 100 (100 percent)
Then set each `startoffset` manually.
But you then need to add rotation for the left or right text

```html
<svg width="50%" viewBox="0 0 200 80" style="background:beige">
  <style>
    path { stroke: red }
    textPath { fill:blue; dominant-baseline:middle; text-anchor:middle }
  </style>
  <path id="P1" d="M10 10h180"/>
  <path id="P2" d="M190 10v70"/>
  <path id="P3" d="M10 80v-70"/>
  <text font-size="8px">
    <textPath href="#P1" startoffset="50%">TOP</textPath>
    <textPath href="#P2" startoffset="50%">LEFT</textPath>
    <textPath href="#P3" startoffset="50%">RIGHT</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the thing is that in my example border is only one `path`. Can you show an example on my svg?

Comment: No, you have to learn SVG yourself, we are not here to do your job. I gave you the instructions using ``pathLength``